# Error : Path must be a string, NodeJS Read/Write

Tags: javascript, node.js

What i'm trying to do is read/write to multiple files at once, Once a file is created, only the data inside the file would be changed.

code:

```
var files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname+"/")

function readWrite(files) {
    fs.readFile(files[i], 'utf-8', function(err, data){
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        fs.writeFile(files[i], 'test string', 'utf-8', function (err) {
            if (err){
                console.log("completed")
            }
        })
    })
}


for(i in files){
    readWrite(files[i])
}
```

The error is pretty obvious "path must be a string", But how do I go about writing to multiple files in the same directory at once?

I'm pretty new to node, so sorry if this seems like a bonehead question, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing filename to readWrite function so you should not use `[i]`:

```
function readWrite(file) {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        fs.writeFile(file, 'test string', 'utf-8', function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("completed")
            }
        })
    })
}


for (i in files) {
    readWrite(files[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `files[i]` by `files` inside your function. You should be using the name of your variable, `files` (and probably rename it to `filepath`)

After that, do you really want to read and write from the same file at the same time (this is what your code is doing) ?

Comment: Don't you have to read from the file before you write to it? Thats what I thought at least.